# APPDYNAMICS Public Rest APIs info

Tags: rest, appdynamics, app-dynamics-query-language

I'm new to APPDYNAMCS and looking for APPDYNAMICS Public Rest APIs for the below data. I'm able to find out a few of them but not all. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in Advance

Looking for REST APIs for the below data.
1.Configuration Items( Business Application, servers, business service, etc) and relationship among them.
2.Service Map data.
3.Raw Event.
4.Alert data.
5.Raw Metrics.
6.Raw Logs.
7.Raw Traces.
8.SLO/SLI data.
9.Real User Monitoring / Synthetic Monitoring data
10.User sessions data

Answer (score 0):

All currently available AppDynamics APIs are documented here: https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO21/AppDynamics+APIs

The main page includes a summary of what is available.

Answer (score 0):

While ingmar is technically correct, the documentation doesnt cover all the APIs available. There are undocumented APIs that even that AppDynamics utilities on github use.

There is a utility called [AppDynamics command line tool](https://github.com/Appdynamics/api-commandline-tool) which does a good job at documenting the APIs. The commands are listed in its [commands.yml](https://github.com/Appdynamics/api-commandline-tool/blob/master/commands.yml) file.

Another source of API knowledge is  my own [rapport for appdynamics project](https://github.com/open768/rapport) in which I use some of these undocumented APIs after having figured out how the controller uses them.

good luck!